# Query SQL Column Date Range

Tags: sql

I'm having an issue at the moment whereby I've been presented with a database that has its data layed out as follows:

```
'ID | CALCULATIONS | 2015-06 | 2015-07 | 2015-08 | 2015-09
  1    Spend          100        300       
  1    Forecast       200        200       300       800
  2    Spend          300        400       600       300
  2    Forecast       200         0        900       200
  1    Spend                               400       700
```

I know how to write a 'conventional' query based on calculating a spend between say two columns i.e

`ID | CALCULATIONS | Date    |  Amount
 1    Spend         01/06/15     100`

But is there a way to perform a query based on the layout of my current (problimatic) database?
For example select x From x where date is between y & z ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: have you tried anything at all?

Comment: Ask for a better formatted table, one with a date column.

Comment: so they add a column for every month?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I agree with the folks suggesting the `UNION` below to "unpivot" the data before querying. If this is a lot of columns of dates, or something you have to do regularly as more data comes in, consider a stored procedure that dynamically writes this sql and submits it. Then you can just do a nice friendly query against using `BETWEEN`

Answer (score 1):

My best advice would be to create a view to put the table in a saner format:

```
create view v_table as
    select id, calculations, '2015-06' as yyyymm, ?2015-06? as value
    from t
    union all
    select id, calculations, '2015-07' as yyyymm, ?2015-07? as value
    from t
    union all
    . . .;
```

You can then use `v_table` to write the queries that you want.  Note that the `?` in the above is meant to be whatever escape delimiter is used for your database, typically double quotes, backticks, or square braces.

The "date" is a string in the format YYYY-MM, which can be used for equality and between comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a unpivot.  There are different ways to do it in various SQL systems, the "standard" SQL way would be something like:

```
Select ID, Calculations, '2015-06-01' As Date, [2015-06] As Amount
UNION
Select ID, Calculations, '2015-07-01' As Date, [2015-07] As Amount
UNION
Select ID, Calculations, '2015-08-01' As Date, [2015-08] As Amount
UNION
Select ID, Calculations, '2015-09-01' As Date, [2015-09] As Amount
```

Using the appropriate db-specific methods to convert `'2015-06-01'` to a DateTime value, and appropriate delimiters to reference the column `2015-06` by name.

Comment: `[2015-08]` is not "standard" SQL

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name True - added that caveat.